# how matplotlib create and deliver plot to jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook, we can use %matplotlib inline to guide inline the image created by python script. Can anyone give a 5 sentence explaining what is happening under the hood to make that happen? If i'd like to have some web page to host the matplotlib created plot, is that possible or not? thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline backend essentially calls `fig.savefig(buffer, format="png", bbox_inches="tight")` where `fig` is the figure to show. It'll then supply the content of `buffer` inside a `<img>` tag in the jupyter's output section.